# is there any tool/lib for javascript log in server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, typescript

The application developed in React Js.

Problem :
Not able to find the root cause If the customer facing any issues (not able to reproduce),to resolve; persistent log is required for analyze the issues.
It would be great if someone help me to resolve the issues.

thanks.

Comment: Asking for libraries is considered off-topic on SO. It's unclear at which point you intend to add log entries. Any way, Winston is most popular lib for Node.

Answer (score 0):

> Not able to find the root cause If the customer facing any issues (not able to reproduce),to resolve; persistent log is required for analyze the issues

There are lots of services for that. A few I have used:

- Mixpanel https://mixpanel.com/ < you send events effectively "logs"
- TrackJS : https://trackjs.com/ < will track errors automatically for you.